# How to prove dim(N(T)) = 1 for a nilpotent linear function of order n.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $T$ be a linear operator on $\mathbb V$ such that $T^{n}$ = $0$ but $T^{n-1} \neq 0$ how Can I prove that $dim(N(T)) = 1$?

I have tried to prove a lemma that can help me prove the said question.

If $dim(T^{p}) = dim(T^{p+1}) \Rightarrow dim(T^{p+1}) = dim(T^{p+2})$

I can prove the lemma for $p = 1$ using isomorphism, but I get stuck when $p > 1$.

** $dim(V)$ = $n$

Comment: I should have said that $dim V$ = $n$.

Comment: *Hint*: Let $v\notin\ker T^{n-1}$.  What can you say about $v,Tv,T^2v,T^3v,\dots,T^{n-1}v$?

Comment: you may want to consider the monotone sequence $\text{rank}\big(T\big)\geq \text{rank}\big(T^2\big)\geq \text{rank}\big(T^3\big)\geq \dots$ and then examine the equality conditions of $ \text{rank}\big(B\big)\geq \text{rank}\big(AB\big)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $T^{n-1} \neq {0}$ then there is a vector such that $T^{n-1}v \neq 0 $  now  we will prove that the set {$v$,$Tv$,$\dots$,$T^{n-1}v$} is a basis for $\mathbb{V}$ and for this we need to prove that they are independent. We will do this using proof by contradiction. Lets say they are not independent so there are coefficients {$a_1, a_2, \dots, a_{n}$} such that:

\begin{align}
a_1v + a_2Tv + \dots + a_nT^{n-1}v = 0
\end{align}
by applying the $T^{n-1}$ operator to both sides we will have:
\begin{align}
a_1T^{n-1}v = 0 \Rightarrow a_1 = 0
\end{align}
and using the same logic we can deduce that $a_1 = a_2 = \dots = a_n = 0$ and we reach a contradiction.

Now we can represent the $T$ operator using this new basis which will give us a matrix with columns {$e_2,e_3,\dots,e_n,0$} with $e_{i}$ being the  i-th standard basis. The rank of this matrix is $n-1$ from which follows that $dim(N(T)) = 1$